# Parse Hosting Multiple Custom Domains

Tags: parse-platform

How would you implement multiple custom domains to point to a Parse App (myapp.parseapp.com)? Right now there is only space for one domain on the Parse dashboard but I need multiple domains to point to it and I'd prefer not to simply redirect the domains to a different one, but rather have each domain point to it. Heroku has this functionality but Parse doesn't seem to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Register your own domains and add CNAMEs to myapp.parseapp.com